# rspec-rails: Failure/Error: get "/" No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

Trying out rspec-rails. I get a weird error - no routes are supposedly found, even though I can access them fine in the browser when running rails s.

I even tried it with just /

```
Failure/Error: get "/"
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"action_view/test_case/test", :action=>"/"}
```

I can definitely access / and other resources in the browser, though. Is there something I could've missed when setting rspec up? I put it into the Gemfile and ran rspec:install.

Thank you,
MrB

edit: Here's my test

```
  1 require 'spec_helper'
  2 
  3 describe "resource" do
  4   describe "GET" do
  5     it "contains /" do
  6       get "/"
  7       response.should have_selector("h1", :content => "Project")
  8     end
  9   end
 10 end
```

Here's my route file:

```
myApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :groups do
    resources :projects
  end 

  resources :projects do
    resources :variants
    resources :steps

    member do
      get 'compare'
    end 
  end 

  resources :steps do
    resources :costs
  end 

  resources :variants do
    resources :costs
  end 

  resources :costs

  root :to => "home#index"

end
```

My spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'    

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.include RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup


  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"


  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```

Didn't really change anything here, I think.

Comment: Can you post your spec_helper.rb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i know, you are trying to combine two tests into one. In rspec this should be solved in two steps. In one spec you test the routing, and in another you test the controller.

So, add a file `spec/routing/root_routing_spec.rb`

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "routes for Widgets" do
  it "routes /widgets to the widgets controller" do
    { :get => "/" }.should route_to(:controller => "home", :action => "index")
  end
end
```

And then add a file `spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb`, and I am using the extended matchers defined by shoulda or remarkable.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe HomeController do

  render_views

  context "GET index" do
    before(:each) do
      get :index
    end
    it {should respond_with :success }
    it {should render_template(:index) }

    it "has the right title" do
      response.should have_selector("h1", :content => "Project")
    end

  end
end
```

Actually, I almost never use `render_views` but always test my components as isolated as possible. Whether the view contains the correct title I test in my view-spec.

Using rspec i test each component (model, controller, views, routing) separately, and i use cucumber to write high level tests to slice through all layers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `describe` a controller for a controller test. Also, since you're testing the contents of the view in the controller test and not a separate view spec, you have to `render_views`.

```
describe SomeController, "GET /" do
  render_views

  it "does whatever" do
    get '/'
    response.should have_selector(...)
  end
end
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to help either, / still unfound. I'm actually not trying to test a controller specifically. I just want to test if I get the correct view, so I guess it's more of a view test than a controller test. Or maybe all-in-one. But neither putting the controller into the describe nor putting 'render_views' in helped :-(

Comment: If it's a view spec then you shouldn't be accessing a route at all. See http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-5/dir/view-specs/view-spec for examples.